# Conditional Breakpoint, EBP contains string pointer

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, ollydbg, conditional-breakpoint

I need to use a conditional breakpoint to find the location when `EBP-44` contains the pointer to a specific string. I tried using **ollydbg**, but because `EBP-44` is mostly 0 (or other unreadable memory) the Run Trace fails with `Run trace: invalid condition 1 - Unable to get contents of memory`. Is there any way to do this?

My condition:

```
[ASCII [EBP-1C]]=="MYSTRING"
```

This condition is only triggered once in the code

Comment: You can try using conditional breakpoints in GDB. I'd recommend looking into http://blog.vinceliu.com/2009/07/gdbs-conditional-breakpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

tool ollydbg 1.10

code for demo

```
ebp-44:\>dir /b
ebp-44.cpp

ebp-44:\>type ebp-44.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main (void)
{
    char *mystrarray[]  = {
        "humble bee", "bumblebee", NULL,"my naughty string", "my notty string",
        "my nauty string","my native string",NULL, "want to string me ",
        "come on string with me","string sings the song strong", NULL, NULL,
        "what's this string doing here in onederlaand", NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
        "teaching lice to string the strong","my golden bug is strumming here",
        "my gold trinket's stringing here", "my gold trinket's stringing hare",
        "want to string me ","come string me", "string sings the song strong",
        NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"my gold trinket's stringing hire",NULL,NULL
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < _countof(mystrarray) ; i++ )
    {
        register char *yoyo;
        yoyo = mystrarray[i];
        printf("%s\n", yoyo);
    }
    return 0;
}
ebp-44:\>cl /nologo /Zi /analyze /W4 ebp-44.cpp /link /RELEASE
ebp-44.cpp

ebp-44:\>ebp-44.exe
humble bee
bumblebee
(null)
my naughty string
my notty string
my nauty string
my native string
(null)
want to string me
come on string with me
string sings the song strong
(null)
(null)
what's this string doing here in onederlaand
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
teaching lice to string the strong
my golden bug is strumming here
my gold trinket's stringing here
my gold trinket's stringing hare
want to string me
come string me
string sings the song strong
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
my gold trinket's stringing hire
(null)
(null)

ebp-44:\>OLLYDBG.EXE ebp-44.exe

ebp-44:\>
```

set a `breakpoint on main and f9` to run the exe
when it breaks on main 
hit `ctrl+t  (condition to pause run trace)`
`check mark condition is true` checkbox
in the condition box enter

```
STRING [[ EBP-90]] == "my gold trinket's stringing hare"
```

{EBP-90] is taken from viewing the disassembly may vary in your case use appropriate address

```
0040111A   |MOV     ECX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8C]             ; yoyo = mystrarray[i];
00401120   |MOV     EDX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+ECX*4-88]
00401127   |MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-90], EDX
0040112D   |MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-90]             ; printf("%s\n", yoyo);
00401133   |PUSH    EAX
00401134   |PUSH    ebp-44.0041235C
00401139   |CALL    ebp-44.printf
```

hit ctrl+f11 (trace into)

ollydbg will break when [ebp-90] contains the string

```
Log data, item 0
 Message=Conditional pause: STRING [[ EBP-90]] == "my gold trinket's stringing hare"
```

see the assembly above edx is trnsferring our string to [ebp-90]

```
EDX=004122D0 (ebp-44.004122D0), ASCII "my gold trinket's stringing hare"
Stack SS:[0013FEE8]=004122D0 (ebp-44.004122D0), ASCII "my gold trinket's stringing hare"
ebp-44.cpp:18.  yoyo = mystrarray[i];
```

here is a print of ebp when broken

```
Log data, item 0
 Message=ebp  = 13ff78  ebp-90 = 13fee8   [ebp-90] = 4122d0  [[ebp-90]]  = 6720796d  STRING [[ebp-90]]  = my gold trinket's stringing hare " see 6d792067 ascii equivalent for "my g"
```